# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml, maven-site-plugin

Trying to generate `mvn site` with maven 3  fails and I cannot get why. Calling the site generation with:

```
mvn3 -e clean site -Pmetrics
```

Results in:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site (default-site) on
>   project mi-scenarios: Execution default-site of goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site failed: No match
>   found -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site
>   (default-site) on project mi-scenarios: Execution default-site of goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site failed: No match
>   found     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:224)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)   at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)    at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)   at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
>   Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution
>   default-site of goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site failed: No match
>   found     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
>     ... 20 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match
>   found     at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:536)  at
>   com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.javadoc.JavadocMethodCheck.getMultilineNoArgTags(JavadocMethodCheck.java:669)
>     at
>   com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.javadoc.JavadocMethodCheck.getMethodTags(JavadocMethodCheck.java:598)
>     at
>   com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.javadoc.JavadocMethodCheck.checkComment(JavadocMethodCheck.java:478)
>     at
>   com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.javadoc.JavadocMethodCheck.processAST(JavadocMethodCheck.java:365)
>     at
>   com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.AbstractTypeAwareCheck.visitToken(AbstractTypeAwareCheck.java:147)
>     at
>   com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.TreeWalker.notifyVisit(TreeWalker.java:388)
>     at
>   com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.TreeWalker.processIter(TreeWalker.java:499)
>     at
>   com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.TreeWalker.walk(TreeWalker.java:330)
>     at
>   com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.TreeWalker.processFiltered(TreeWalker.java:207)
>     at
>   com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.AbstractFileSetCheck.process(AbstractFileSetCheck.java:79)
>     at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Checker.process(Checker.java:265)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.checkstyle.exec.DefaultCheckstyleExecutor.executeCheckstyle(DefaultCheckstyleExecutor.java:252)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.checkstyle.AbstractCheckstyleReport.executeReport(AbstractCheckstyleReport.java:473)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.checkstyle.CheckstyleReport.executeReport(CheckstyleReport.java:154)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.generate(AbstractMavenReport.java:255)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugins.site.ReportDocumentRenderer.renderDocument(ReportDocumentRenderer.java:219)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DefaultSiteRenderer.renderModule(DefaultSiteRenderer.java:319)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DefaultSiteRenderer.render(DefaultSiteRenderer.java:135)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugins.site.SiteMojo.renderLocale(SiteMojo.java:175)
>     at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.SiteMojo.execute(SiteMojo.java:138)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
>     ... 21 more

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>edu.una.miscenarios</groupId>
    <artifactId>mi-scenarios</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mi-scenarios</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>edu.una.miscenarios.start.Start</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javatuples</groupId>
            <artifactId>javatuples</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.gmu.cs</groupId>
            <artifactId>mason</artifactId>
            <version>19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.gmu.cs</groupId>
            <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
            <version>23.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>infodynamics</groupId>
            <artifactId>infodynamics</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.una.dependencylib</groupId>
            <artifactId>dependencylib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
                    <effort>Max</effort>
                    <failOnError>false</failOnError>
                    <sourceEncoding>${file.encoding}</sourceEncoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                            <report>checkstyle</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>metrics</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.10.3</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>aggregate</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
                            <findbugsXmlWithMessages>true</findbugsXmlWithMessages>
                            <failOnError>false</failOnError>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>run-findbugs</id>
                                <phase>verify</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>check</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.17</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>check</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>verify</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.7</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <formats>
                                <format>xml</format>
                                <format>html</format>
                            </formats>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>cobertura</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>verify</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is probably caused by the maven checkstyle plugin. Look at the following line from the build output:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:536) at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.javadoc.JavadocMethodCheck.getMultilineNoArgTags(JavadocMethodCheck.java:669)
```

This is real error. If the error is the same as described [here](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/2398) and [here](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/2461), then it's a bug of the plugin when encountering a `@return` javadoc tag which is not followed by any text.

**Solution**: adding text after the `@return` tag fixes the issue, which is a good practice by the way, to have javadoc properly filled with the right information :)

**Quick test**: remove the checkstyle plugin and run it again. If it works, then you isolated the issue, then look for `@return` tags without text and fix them.

Comment: Thanks saves my day! The issue however still persist in 2.17

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had no empty `@return`. I was actually missing the doxia classes.

My error was a bit different also:

> Execution default-site of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site: org/apache/maven/doxia/siterenderer/DocumentContent

I just needed to add the plugin to my POM:

```xml
...
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven.site.plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
        </pluginManagement>
...
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Note: the plugin is to be installed in the `build` section, not `reporting` : https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/plugin-info.html#Usage

Then run `mvn site`.